# Get value of a toggle element

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I am building a blade toggle component using AlpineJS. The idea is that you can enable/disable the UI toggle and a invissible checkbox will be put on/on

toggle.blade.php:

```
<div x-data="{on: false}">
    <button type="button" @click="on = !on" :class="{'bg-cyan-600' : on, 'bg-gray-200' : !on}">
        <span :class="{'translate-x-5' : on, 'translate-x-0' : !on}" class="..."></span>
    </button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$name}}" x-model="on" value="on" class="hidden" />
</div>
```

This is working good so far. I can put the toggle in my form and toggle it:

```
<x-toggle name="test" />
```

But now I want other elements interact with this toggle. For example make another input field vissible by toggling the test-toggle on.

So it need to work something like this:

```
<div x-data="{show: false}">
    <x-toggle name="test" x-model="show" />
    
    <div x-show="show">
        <!-- input elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scenario with two alpine components, We need an inter-component communication to achieve the functionality.

Since alpine.js does not support accessing parent's or child's components, we can make use of events to handle this.

We can `watch` the `on` property in the `toggle.blade.php` and emit an event with the updated value.

toggle.blade.php:

```html
<div x-data="{on: false}" x-init="$watch('on', val => $dispatch('toggle',val))">
    <button type="button" @click="on = !on" :class="{'bg-cyan-600' : on, 'bg-gray-200' : !on}">
        <span :class="{'translate-x-5' : on, 'translate-x-0' : !on}" class="..."></span>
    </button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$name}}" x-model="on" value="on" class="hidden" />
</div>
```

Now in the parent, we can listen for the event `toggle` and set the `show` property accordingly.

```html
<div x-data="{show: false}" @toggle="show = $event.detail">
    <x-toggle name="test" />
    
    <div x-show="show">
        <!-- input elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the parent will listen for the toggle event and update the data property.

This is the simplest possible way to handle inter-component communication in `alphine.js`.

But there's an option to handle it with `states`. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612231/how-to-access-a-property-or-a-method-of-alpine-js-parent-component-from-a-child) for more detailed description.